# I need help to SUM an array with 5 distinct values in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

the problem is that after the second index value it stops, so it goes ->
array[0] + array[1] -> gets stuck here
causing to the output to be 1...3 and forever 3 :(

this is my code by now:

```
.data
c:.word 1,2,3,4,5

.text

    la $s2, c
    li $t2, 0

loop:        



    add $t2, $t2, $t2 # 2*i
    add $t2, $t2, $t2 # 4*i
    add $t1, $t2, $s2 # a[i] = (4*i + $s2)
    lw  $t0, 0($t1)   # $t1 = a[i]
    add $s0, $s0, $t0 # g = h + a[i]

    li $v0, 1
    la $a0, ($s0)
    syscall

    add $t2, $t2, 1
    beq $s0, 15, endLoop

    j loop

endLoop:

    li $v0, 1
    la $a0, ($s0)
    syscall
```

Comment: `beq $s0, 15, endLoop` is testing `$s0` which you use as a temporary inside the loop.  Did you mean to check `$t2`?

Comment: i need to go to endLoop when the SUM gets to 15 cause my array values are 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Oh yes, I see, I didn't look carefully enough.  If you know what the answer is, you don't need to loop in the first place.  You should be checking `do {} while($t2 != 5)`.  Also, you double `$t2` (twice) inside the loop instead of using a temporary.  And instead of that, you could just `addu $s2, $s2, 4` like to increment the pointer.  Or at least use a left shift by 2 like `sll $t3, $t2, 2` to scale by 4 into a temporary.

Comment: I'm surprised your loop doesn't fault for loading an invalid pointer at some point.  Your index quickly grows huge.  Anyway, single-step your code in the debugger and it should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks a LOT Peter, check my new code, it worked just fine like that, at least until now :)

Comment: Now you have a lot of useless instructions.  `$t2` stays zero the whole time (and if it didn't, your loop would be broken again because your `$t2` index handling is still broken).  Also, post answers as answers, not edits to the question.

Comment: what do u think its better then? and ok, sorry.. im learning how to use this. Ill try my best!

Comment: Remove all the `add $t2` and `$t1` instructions and just keep the `lw $0, ($s2)`.  You're doing a pointer-increment *instead of* array indexing.

Comment: im not sure how to do this and i dont want the code to stop working, im not really good on assembly :P but ill try to

Comment: Rolled back to the version that still has the bug the question is asking about, otherwise it's not even a question.

Comment: okay, did u see the new way i did it, better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.data
c: .word 1,1,1,1,1

.text
    la $s2, c
    li $t2, 0
    li $t5, 0

loop:        
    add $t2, $t2, $t2 # 2*i
    add $t2, $t2, $t2 # 4*i
    add $t1, $t2, $s2 # a[i] = (4*i + $s2)
    lw  $t0, 0($t1)   # $t1 = a[i]
    add $s0, $s0, $t0 # g = h + a[i]

    li $v0, 1
    la $a0, ($s0)
    syscall

    add $t5, $t5, 1
    add $s2, $s2, 4
    beq $t5, 5 , fimLoop

    j loop

fimLoop:

    li $v0, 1
    la $a0, ($s0)
    syscall
```

Comment: This fixes the loop-exit condition to not assume the result, but you're still uselessly doing `$t2 <<= 2` every iteration when `$t2` is always zero.  Also, `la $a0, ($s0)` is a really weird way to write `move $a0, $s0`.  I'm surprised `la` even accepts it.  It's not an address so for human readers it makes zero sense.

Comment: And your comments don't match what the code is actually doing.  You're doing `a++` instead of `i++`  I guess you are technically still calculating the address of `a[i]` and using that, even though `i` is always zero.